# SSIS Execute process task error with SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to set up a package in SSIS in SQL 2014. When I deploy this to run automatically I get the following error.

> SQLCMD error execution to determine the current environment reference Id failed Process Exit code 1.

I have no idea what this error is or how I can prevent it. I am assuming it is a parameter or something This is the first step in the package and it does not give me any more information.

Comment: Guessing you're using an execute process task in your SSIS package and calling `sqlcmd`? Is so, why? SSIS has an Execute T-SQL task.

Comment: no the only step is to add a date to a field on a table pretty simple package.

Comment: And how are are you doing that? That error is saying you're using `sqlcmd`, what what does `sqlcmd` have to do with any of this?